How can I implement an audio CAPTCHA reader with django-simple-captcha in Django?
I'm looking to enhance the accessibility of my Django web application by integrating an audio CAPTCHA reader alongside the text-based CAPTCHA provided by django-simple-captcha. While the text-based CAPTCHA is effective for most users, some users may have difficulty reading the text due to visual impairments or other reasons.
I've read the documentation, but I can't understand how to implement... https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#captcha-sox-path

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
